# Convert string to seconds of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update duration of time in seconds for more that 24 hours a day which should be updated in new column for seconds

```
update [dbo].[DurationLoad]
set [DurationInSeconds] = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', [Duration_LoadValue] )) 
where [Duration_LoadValue] is not null
```

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationLoad](
[Sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Duration_LoadValue] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
[DurationInSeconds] [decimal](10, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO 

 INSERT [dbo].[DurationLoad] ([Sno], [Duration_LoadValue], [DurationInSeconds]) 
VALUES 
(1, N' 21:50', NULL),
(2, N' 23:38', NULL),
(3, N' 27:50', NULL),
(4, N' 33:47', NULL),
(5, N'-114.25', NULL),
(6, N'75:15', NULL),
(7, N'-126.34', NULL) 




Select  [Duration_LoadValue]  , (DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', [Duration_LoadValue] )) 
FROM [dbo].[DurationLoad]
where [Duration_LoadValue] is not null

update [dbo].[DurationLoad]
set [DurationInSeconds] = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', [Duration_LoadValue] )) 
where [Duration_LoadValue] is not null
```

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
select * from [dbo].[DurationLoad]
```

Duration in seconds is expected for the above values

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal here. `33:47` is not a time (time can only have 24 hours), `-114.25` is not a time either. Can you add expected values?

Comment: durationload is int value not datetime then how will you apply datediff?

Comment: i have got the values from an source excel file where it calculated duration difference between 2 dates.

Comment: Its not an time column, its and decimal where it stores the time values

Comment: this is not duplicate. kindly revert me the values since my Duraion_LoadValues is not date datattype